# How to upload a captured photo to REST interface using JSON - JQuery by PhoneGap (iPhone)?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

My application asks from the user to capture an photo and then upload it to the server if the user is online. The code for the photo capture I took from [PhoneGap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html). How can I use the imgURL to upload it to the REST interface using Json and Jquery mobile?

The code I have up to now is:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
// Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
// console.log(imageData);

// Get image handle
//
var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

// Unhide image elements
//
smallImage.style.display = 'block';

// Show the captured photo
// The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
//
smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

}

Again, it is the same code taken from the PhoeGap API... I appreciate any help!...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly.

You should have your rest url and data structure (in JSON) the endpoint expects. 
Once you have the base64 encoded string Use [JSON](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) library for packing JSON data and then send it to the service using 
[jquery.ajax().](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Edited to include the post code

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: yoururl,
  data: jsondata,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

Content type will usually be

```
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
```

and datatype will be

```
dataType: 'json'
```

Comment: I was actually wondering which jQuery function should I use to implement the upload to the server. The rest already exists so I now need to write the uploading function

Comment: Edited the answer to include the function

Comment: @ user: In the data:jsondata part I should have my variables with the information? I need to upload three parameters. So how should I write them? Their names separated in coma?

Comment: What I would suggest is look at JSON library (linked in my answer). You can pack your data into a JSON object and then call JSON.Stringify to convert that to string.